# Exception org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any], Int)] in scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter4j, rdd

Using Below code I am getting tweets for a particular filter :

```
val topCounts60 = tweetMap.map((_, 1)).

reduceByKeyAndWindow(_+_, Seconds(60*60))
```

one of the sample Output of topCounts60 is in below format if i do topCounts60.println():

```
(Map(UserLang -> en, UserName -> Harmeet Singh, UserScreenName -> 
harmeetsingh060, HashTags -> , UserVerification -> false, Spam -> true,     UserFollowersCount -> 44, UserLocation -> भारत, UserStatusCount -> 50,   UserCreated -> 2016-07-04T06:32:49.000+0530, UserDescription -> Punjabi Music,   TextLength -> 118, Text -> RT @PMOIndia: The Prime Minister is chairing a high   level meeting on the situation in Kashmir,    UserFollowersRatio -> 0.32116788625717163, UserFavouritesCount -> 67,   UserFriendsCount -> 137, StatusCreatedAt -> 2016-07-12T21:07:30.000+0530,   UserID -> 749770405867556865),1)
```

Now I am trying to print each key pair values like below:

```
for ((k,v) <- topCounts60) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Error:(125, 10) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required:     org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any], Int)]
for ((k,v) <- topCounts60) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)
```

How to get output like below :

```
UserLang -> en,

UserName -> Harmeet Singh
```

I am beginner in scala,have no clue how to print all values seperatley,please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` and string interpolation:

```
rdd.collect().foreach { case (k,v) => println(s"key: $s, value: $v")`}
```

Comment: @AkshayAnand ah, you use for comprehension for `RDD` types :) That's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
topCounts60.foreachRDD {
    rdd => for ((k,v) <- rdd.collect) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)
}
```

Comment: its coming in below format:

key: Map(UserLang -> en, UserName -> Deepesh Kumar, UserScreenName -> afg5859, HashTags -> , UserVerification -> false, Spam -> true, UserFollowersCount -> 49, UserLocation -> Planet Earth, UserStatusCount -> 640, UserCreated -> 2016-01-04T14:51:59.000+0530, UserDescription -> I Practice, TextLength -> 110, Text ->@AnupamPkher exceptions are not the rule,  the support for terrorism in Kashmir is appalling., UserFollowersRatio -> 0.19521912932395935),
value: 1

Cant I break it more individually..I want to use case case class and store in spark sql