# scala Map[(String, String),Int] to build corresponding MAP[String,String]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How to transform:

```
(Map(UserLang -> en, UserName -> a),1)
(Map(UserLang -> jp, UserName -> b),1)
```

to

```
 (UserLang -> en, UserName -> a)
 (UserLang -> jp, UserName -> b)
```

How to do this via functional programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
val map1: Map[(String, String),Int]
val map2: Map[String, String] = map1.keySet.toMap
```

`.keySet` discards the `Int` and turns your `Map[(String, String),Int]` into a `Set[(String,String)]` which you can then easily convert to a `Map`by calling `toMap`.

Comment: I am doing this in spark using scala,your example gave me idea atleast how to proceed there,thanks :)

Comment: If you expand on your question, I can also add more details to my answer :) Then we can also help people who might encounter this problem in the future!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333479/exception-org-apache-spark-rdd-rddscala-collection-immutable-mapstring-any

after getting your pointer,I am able to seggregate wanted MAP,using below code:
 topCounts60.foreachRDD( rdd => {
      for(item <- rdd.keys.collect().toArray) {
        println(item);
      }
    })

Comment: Maybe you should put that into your question, or feel free to edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`(Map(UserLang -> en, UserName -> a),1)` is type `(Map[String,String], Int)` and not `Map[(String,String),Int]` as stated in the question title.

For the former, try `map(_._1)`.  For the latter try `keys.toMap`.